# Вычесть дату и перевести в дни

Tags: python

и так, у меня есть нынешняя дата `03.11.21` - 3 ноября 21 года мне из этой даты нужно отнять другую дату `18.3.19` - 18 марта 19 года и перевести результат в дни

Comment: Где ж вы слово "вычтить" нашли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто

```py
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
any_day = date(2019,3,18)
print((today - any_day).days)

961
```

[Документация здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

```py
any_day = date(2021,10,9)
print((today - any_day).days)

25
```

Comment: не работает, при дате 9.10.21 пишет 730510 @Dmitry

Comment: я не знаю как через datetime получить год полностью, не 21 а 2021 @Dmitry

Comment: @boostyoiu добавил в ответ. Если возникают новые вопросы то лучше всего если вы будете создавать новый вопрос. В данном случае вам необходимо разобраться с форматом даты, который вы используете

Comment: я получаю дату так,     rY = int(member.created_at.strftime("%y"))
    rM = int(member.created_at.strftime("%m"))
    rD = int(member.created_at.strftime("%d"))

Comment: и у вас только последние две цифры? тогда можно захаркодить и приплюсовать 2000

Comment: всё, заработало, спасибо

Comment: наслаждайтесь) [что делать с ответами на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)